# How to return a multidimensional static array from a function in c

Tags: c, matrix, multidimensional-array, static, return-type

I want to return a multidimensional matrix from a function.

So I know how to do that through a struct and dynamic allocating. But I'm not sure how to do that with a static multidimensional array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
static int **function(){
    static int array[5][10];
    return array;
}
int main(void){
    int** test;
    test = function();
    return 0;
}
```

The Gcc keep emiting this warning:

> Warning: returning 'int (*)[10]' from a function with
> incompatible return type 'int **' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
> return array;

And I want to understand why?

Comment: The error message actually contains the actual type you're returning: "returning 'int (*)[10]' ". That's the return type you need. You might want to create a type-alias (using `typedef`) for it.

Comment: As for understanding what's happening, remember that arrays *decays* to pointers to their first element. That is, when you do `return array;` then `array` decay to `&array[0]`. And since `array[0]` is an array of ten `int` elements, the type of `&array[0]` is "pointer to array of ten `int`", or `int (*)[10]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this return statement

```
return array;
```

the array designator `array` is converted to pointer to its first element of the type `int ( * )[10]`.   But the function return type is `int **`. There is no implicit conversion from the type `int ( * )[10]` to the type `int **`. So the compiler will issue an error.

Pay attention to that the user of the function needs to know the sizes of the array.

So I advise you to declare the function like

```
static int ( *function( void ) )[5][10]
{
    static int array[5][10];
    return &array;
}
```

and then in main you can write

```
int ( *test )[5][10] = function();
```

dereferencing the pointer `test` you will get the array.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum { M = 5, N = 10 };

static int ( *function( void ) )[M][N] 
{
    static int array[M][N] =
    {
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 },
        { 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3 },
        { 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4 },
        { 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 }
    };
    
    return &array;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int ( *test )[M][N] = function();
    
    printf( "The size of the array is %zu\n", sizeof( *test ) );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < M; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%d ", ( *test )[i][j] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
The size of the array is 200
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

You can introduce an alias for the array type the following way to make the function declaration simpler

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum { M = 5, N = 10 };

typedef int Array[M][N];

static Array * function( void ) 
{
    static Array array =
    {
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 },
        { 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3 },
        { 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4 },
        { 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 }
    };
    
    return &array;
}

int main(void) 
{
    Array *test = function();
    
    printf( "The size of the array is %zu\n", sizeof( *test ) );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < M; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%d ", ( *test )[i][j] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a big difference between a "pointer to a pointer" and a "pointer to an array".  In your case, you need a "pointer to an array", which requires knowing the second dimension of the array.  Try the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int (*function(void))[10] {
    static int array[5][10];
    return array;
}

int main(void) {
    int (*test)[10];
    test = function();
    return 0;
}
```

Then from `main` you can access it as `test[i][j]`.

Comment: You might want to show a version using a type-alias as well, as that will make thins very much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `void *` function.

```
static void *function(void) 
{
    static int array[5][10];
    return array;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int (*test)[10] = function();
}
```